# Angular ng-repeat in dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to do this with `ng-repeat` in Angular:

```
   <select ng-model="selected_item">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.id}}"
                ng-change="doSomething(selected_item)">
        {{item.name}} - {{item.another_attribute}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

and getting the error `No controller: ngModel`.

Usually I construct dropdowns with `ng-options` but since the label of the options are made up of two different attributes, it doesn't work.

```
<select ng-model="selected_item" 
        ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" 
        ng-change="doSomething(selected_item)">
```

As you can see I cannot use two attributes here for the label.

Any ideas?

Comment: you not injected your ngModel in app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can concatenate strings in the label expression. So

```
ng-options="item.id as (item.name + '-' + item.another_attribute) for item in items"
```

should work just fine.

quick demo: http://jsbin.com/OKoviMA/1/

---

To be more precise, the *label expression* is a *real angular expression*, so you could for example also apply a filter or call a controller method, even passing the current itteration value as a parameter.